# Beamer theme, remove navigation bar from one slide

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I'm using `beamer` and the theme `Copenhagen`. I would like to remove the navigation menu (the list of section names shown at the top of each slide) from the first (first page) and from the summary slides.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can apply the `plain` option to both `frame`s.

Comment: @PaulGaborit but this also removes the footline, and apparently the OP only wants to remove the headline.

Comment: I didn't noticed that since in my slides I've already removed the footline. So, this is no problem at al.

Comment: @JohnTortugo So the `plain` option is the simpler solution.

Comment: @PaulGaborit seems so ;-) Do you want to provide your answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the `headline` beamer template to be empty locally, using   `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`; if the frame has space reserved for a frame title, in addition to the modification mentioned before, you will have to move the frame title upwards for this frame, and this can be done by adding a convenient `\vspace{<length>}` to the `frametitle` template (also locally). A little example removing the navigation bar from the frame containing `\maketitle` and for the frames containing the ToCs generated with `\AtBeginSection`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Summary}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test one
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test two
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test three
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test four
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

For an specific frame the same principle applies:

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Summary}
Some text here
\end{frame}
}
```

A complete example, as required in a comment;

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Summary}
Some text here
\end{frame}
}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test one
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test two
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test three
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The frame title}
test four
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my presentation the second slide, Summary, I made it manually. In the example you provided you're using the \Summary .. can you give me an example that doesn't use that? And also, I don't want the summary appearing at each section start.

Comment: @JohnTortugo sure; in my updated answer I show how the same principle applies to any frame (notice the braces to keep the changes local). If you don't want outlines appearing in every section, suppress the lines `\AtBeginSection{...}`.

Comment: I used `\vspace*{-\headheight}` instead of `\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}` in the above. I guess that is more generic.

Answer (score 16):

A very simple solution uses the `plain` option of the `frame` environment... This option removes the headline and the footline of the current `frame`:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  ...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I want to remove the title bar only. Then what to do ?